# A word for extending one's employment

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So the company evaluates the employees every year and those who satisfy requirements in the evaluation can keep working in the company.

> X is required for ----?

employment extension? expansion? ...?

Answer (score 2):

***[extension](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extension)*** itself has the required meaning and usage for the purpose:

> **1.5** An additional period of time given to someone to hold office or fulfil an obligation.
>   *‘the initial term of appointment is for one year, but an extension of two years is envisaged’*